# Query to return days in each month of the year as a list?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, days, monthcalendar

I've looked online but cannot find a solution that returns what I need and was hoping that the experts on this site could assist me as you have in the past.

I have an SQL database that holds timestamped maintenance calls relating to building equipment.

I can query maintenance information, such as the number of calls, the average work time, average time that calls have been open and I have grouped the results by month (to give a trend over the year).

The next stage is for me to provide an indication of equipment up-time. I have the amount of downtime (for the purposes of this that's the time that calls are open) and I can add a count to give the total pieces of equipment. I would like show the percentage of time that equipment was available for use (uptime), based on the number of hours for each month in the year, the number of items and the total time that calls were open.

e.g.

- **Month - No. Calls Raised - Avg Tool Time(hrs) - Avg time open (hrs) - (required) uptime**
- **Jan**   - 4 - 0.37 - 1.00 - 92%
- **Feb**   - 3 - 0.83 - 35.6 - 87%
- **Mar**   - 5 - 0.50 - 1.85 - 85%
- **Apr**   - 10 - 0.72 - 119.5 - 72%

**etc.**

1. Could someone suggest a query that would return the days in **each** month that I could use within my existing query?
2. In addition (sorry, pushing a bit here) ... if a call is raised in Feb and not closed until April, how could I include that downtime in March? Is there a way to take account of that?

I've included the full query below and I apologies in advance for the formatting (and quality). I should add that this is a hosted database so I cannot add tables or do much other than return values.

Many thanks for any help or guidance you can give.

**SAMPLE QUERY BELOW**

```
`SELECT Description as 'Month', 
(SELECT COUNT(TA_SEQ)
FROM F_TASKS, FASSET, FAREALO, F_CONTRACT  
WHERE TA_TASK_DESC IN ('BREAKDOWN')
AND TA_FKEY_AR_SEQ = AR_SEQ
AND LO_SEQ = AR_FKEY_LO_SEQ
AND ( (LO_DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Facility%') OR ((LO_ROOM_NUMBER IN ('G.19', 'G.20')) AND (LO_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%EXIT') ) )
AND TA_FKEY_CTR_SEQ = CTR_SEQ
AND CTR_SEQ IN  (100,101)
AND (TA_SHORT_DESC LIKE '%Door%' AND AR_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%DOOR%')
AND (TA_HIST_STATUS IS NULL OR TA_HIST_STATUS = 'COMPLETE')
AND TA_STATUS <> 'CANCELLED'
AND DATEPART(mm, TA_DUE_DATE)= A.Number
AND DATEPART(year, TA_DUE_DATE)= DATEPART(year, GETDATE())) AS 'No. Calls Raised', 
((ISNULL((SELECT SUM(TA_TIME_TAKEN)
FROM F_TASKS, F_PPM_DETAILS, F_CONTRACT, FASSET, FAREALO
WHERE TA_TASK_DESC = 'PPM'
AND TA_FKEY_AR_SEQ = AR_SEQ
AND LO_SEQ = AR_FKEY_LO_SEQ
AND ( (LO_DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Facility%') OR (LO_ROOM_NUMBER IN ('G.19', 'G.20')) )
AND AR_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%DOOR%'
AND TA_FKEY_CTR_SEQ = CTR_SEQ 
AND CTR_SEQ NOT IN (100,101)
AND PDET_FKEY_TA_SEQ = TA_SEQ
AND DATEPART(year, TA_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(year, GETDATE())
AND DATEPART(month, TA_DUE_DATE)= A.Number ),0)) +
(ISNULL((SELECT SUM(TA_TIME_TAKEN)
FROM F_TASKS, F_BD_DETAILS, F_CONTRACT, FASSET, FAREALO
WHERE TA_TASK_DESC = 'BREAKDOWN'
AND TA_FKEY_AR_SEQ = AR_SEQ
AND LO_SEQ = AR_FKEY_LO_SEQ
AND ( (LO_DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Facility%') OR ((LO_ROOM_NUMBER IN ('G.19', 'G.20')) AND (LO_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%EXIT') ) )
AND (TA_SHORT_DESC LIKE '%Door%' AND AR_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%DOOR%')
AND TA_FKEY_CTR_SEQ = CTR_SEQ
AND CTR_SEQ IN  (100,101)
AND BDET_FKEY_TA_SEQ = TA_SEQ
AND BDET_CALLER_SOURCE NOT IN ('Minor')
AND DATEPART(year, TA_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(year, GETDATE())
AND DATEPART(month, TA_DUE_DATE)= A.Number )*1.00 /
(SELECT COUNT(TA_SEQ)
FROM F_TASKS, FASSET, FAREALO, F_CONTRACT  
WHERE TA_TASK_DESC IN ('BREAKDOWN')
AND TA_FKEY_AR_SEQ = AR_SEQ
AND LO_SEQ = AR_FKEY_LO_SEQ
AND ( (LO_DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Facility%') OR ((LO_ROOM_NUMBER IN ('G.19', 'G.20')) AND (LO_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%EXIT') ) )
AND TA_FKEY_CTR_SEQ = CTR_SEQ
AND CTR_SEQ IN  (100,101)
AND (TA_SHORT_DESC LIKE '%Door%' AND AR_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%DOOR%')
AND (TA_HIST_STATUS IS NULL OR TA_HIST_STATUS = 'COMPLETE')
AND TA_STATUS <> 'CANCELLED'
AND DATEPART(mm, TA_DUE_DATE)= A.Number
AND DATEPART(year, TA_DUE_DATE)= DATEPART(year, GETDATE())) ,0))) AS 'Avg Tool Time (hrs)',
ISNULL(((SELECT SUM(CASE
WHEN TA_FINISH_DATE < TA_DUE_DATE THEN DATEDIFF(hh, TA_FINISH_DATE, TA_DUE_DATE)
WHEN TA_FINISH_DATE >= TA_DUE_DATE THEN DATEDIFF(hh, TA_DUE_DATE, ISNULL(TA_FINISH_DATE,GETDATE()))
ELSE 0 END)
FROM F_TASKS, F_BD_DETAILS, F_CONTRACT, FASSET, FAREALO
WHERE TA_TASK_DESC = 'BREAKDOWN'
AND TA_FKEY_AR_SEQ = AR_SEQ
AND LO_SEQ = AR_FKEY_LO_SEQ
AND ( (LO_DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Facility%') OR ((LO_ROOM_NUMBER IN ('G.19', 'G.20')) AND (LO_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%EXIT') ) )
AND (TA_SHORT_DESC LIKE '%Door%' AND AR_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%DOOR%')
AND TA_FKEY_CTR_SEQ = CTR_SEQ
AND CTR_SEQ IN (100,101)
AND BDET_FKEY_TA_SEQ = TA_SEQ
AND BDET_CALLER_SOURCE NOT IN ('Minor','Request')
AND DATEPART(year, TA_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(year, GETDATE())
AND DATEPART(month, TA_DUE_DATE)= A.Number)*1.00)/
(SELECT COUNT(TA_SEQ)
FROM F_TASKS, FASSET, FAREALO, F_CONTRACT  
WHERE TA_TASK_DESC IN ('BREAKDOWN')
AND TA_FKEY_AR_SEQ = AR_SEQ
AND LO_SEQ = AR_FKEY_LO_SEQ
AND ( (LO_DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Facility%') OR ((LO_ROOM_NUMBER IN ('G.19', 'G.20')) AND (LO_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%EXIT') ) )
AND TA_FKEY_CTR_SEQ = CTR_SEQ
AND CTR_SEQ IN (100,101)
AND (TA_SHORT_DESC LIKE '%Door%' AND AR_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%DOOR%')
AND (TA_HIST_STATUS IS NULL OR TA_HIST_STATUS = 'COMPLETE')
AND TA_STATUS <> 'CANCELLED'
AND DATEPART(mm, TA_DUE_DATE)= A.Number
AND DATEPART(year, TA_DUE_DATE)= DATEPART(year, GETDATE())),0) AS 'Avg Time Open (hrs)'
FROM Intervals A
WHERE Type = 'Month' 
ORDER BY Number`
```

**END OF QUERY**

Many thanks
Gary

Comment: What does your Intervals table look like?

Comment: @lrb - I'm not sure of that terminology, sorry

Comment: FROM Intervals A <-- This table is a period based table, it seems. What fields are in it?

Comment: @lrb, 'A' refers to the month number, I don't think its a separate table, I assumed it was a built in function of SQL.

Comment: Does your Interval A table have Day information in it? Is it a calendar like table?

Comment: @lrb, I'm afraid I don't really have any more info, I'm not aware of a specific table but can only assume that the month number is used as the variable interval A, which is how the tasks are then grouped.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check if the number of hours in a month should be comprised of working hours in working days only, if not, your percentages may be skewed. This works in sql server 2012 and the DATEFROMPARTS. You may need to come up with your own function for that. I have omitted most of your query for brevity and set your fields to zero. But the basic concept would be similar.

```
SELECT
    Detail.Month,
    Detail.Number,
    SumNoCallsMade=SUM(NoCallsRaised),
    AvgAvgToolTime=AVG(AvgToolTimeHrs),
    AvgAvgTimeOpen=AVG(AvgTimeOpenHrs),
    HoursInMonth=MAX(HoursInMonth),
    AverageUpTime=AVG(AvgToolTimeHrs) / CAST(MAX(Detail.HoursInMonth) AS DECIMAL(18,2)),
    AverageOpenTime=AVG(AvgTimeOpenHrs) / CAST(MAX(Detail.HoursInMonth) AS DECIMAL(18,2))
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        A.Month,
        A.Number,
        NoCallsRaised=0,
        AvgToolTimeHrs=0,
        AvgTimeOpenHrs=0,
        HoursInMonth=(24 * DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEFROMPARTS( DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()),A.Number,1)))))

    FROM 
        Intervals A
    WHERE 
        A.Type = 'Month' 
)AS Detail
GROUP BY
    Detail.Month,
    Detail.Number
ORDER BY 
    Detail.Number
```

Comment: Many thanks for your time and effort, I'll give it a go and get back to you either way.